# How to post a message with a special character to Facebook feed using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can successfully post a message to my Facebook feed using the Facebook Graph API. The script I'm using to achieve this sometimes have to include special characters like "é","è",etc...And when this happens, the message appears with these special characters replaced by question mark (?) instead of the actual character. I've been trying to encode  characters prior to posting it and their shows up as is.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're using UTF-8 encoding. facebook is UTF-8 and will have problems with special characters if you're using the default ANSI.